# Embedding Excel into JSON script

Tags: vba

Looking for some resources online, thought it wouldn't hurt to ask if someone else here might have further advice or helpful links. I'm trying to encode an Excel function / range into a JSON script that I'm POSTing to an API.

The sample JSON needs to go through looking like:

```
{
Name: "John Doe,Jane Doe",
Date: "05/09/15 7:05:10"
}
```

The way I was going to put it through was:

```
sampleBody = "{
        Name: Sheet2.Range("Names"),
        Date: NOW()
        }"
```

Where Names is a named range from Excel that looks like:

```
John Doe
Jane Doe
Emily Doe
```

I'm sure that'll give me a fair share of issues (I took out all the `" & Chr(34) & "` for ease of reading.

Comment: Make sure you're not reinventing the wheel: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
Function convertRangeToList(myRange As Range, delimiter As String) As String
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim arrNames() As Variant

    'redim the array
    ReDim arrNames(myRange - 1)

    'Load the array
    i = 0
    For Each rngCell In myRange
        arrNames(i) = rngCell.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next

    'Join to comma seperate the array
    convertRangeToList Join(arrNames, delimiter)

End Function
```

This will take your range and convert it into a list. You can use it like:

```
mylist = convertRangeToList(Range("names"), ",")
```

Comment: Got it. Is there a way to pass it through as a whole named range? Or is it most efficient/realistic to use a loop?

Comment: The trick is that you need to join each cell together with a comma, which is why I went with the `Join()` function. That takes a single dimension array as an argument and Ranges are more like a two dimension array, so looping the range to put all the values into a single-dim array seemed the most efficient here. It should be a pretty quick loop.

Comment: And... also as Mathieu pointed out in the comments, there is a .bas module for dealing with json. It may be worth checking out. It is a very nice set of code for monkeying with json (writing and parsing) within VBA.

Comment: Great! Appreciate it

Comment: had a little problem with the code but I adjusted it to - `Function convertRangetoList(myRange As Range, delimiter As String) As String
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim arrNames() As Variant
Dim i As Long

'redim the array
ReDim (arrNames(myRange - 1))


'Load the array
i = 0
For Each rngCell In myRange
    arrNames(i) = rngCell.Value
    i = i + 1
Next
    
    ' Join to comma seperate array
    convertRangetoList = Join(arrNames, delimiter)

End Function` I just keep getting this new error that's giving me a type mismatch with the redim line that I can't seem to fix.

Comment: Oh... perhaps that should be `Redim arrNames(Range.cells.count - 1)` That would make more sense.